# Название файлов в Android SDK

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Когда-нибудь в *Android SDK* можно будет называть файлы типа `textView`, а не `text_view` `image_back` и т.п.?

Comment: А что мешает?

Comment: Вопрос из разряда "а можно ли когда-нибудь будет программировать под андройд на питоне". Наверное нет. А в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @argamidon, IDEA не дает.

Это как знаете заставить программиста писать string[] mas, вместо мне привычного string mas[].

Или левшу писать правой рукой. Такое же ощущение появляется

Куда им написать может исправят это?. Ведь им всего то надо добавить [A-Z]

Comment: ![asd](http://snag.gy/KVOla.jpg)

Comment: надеюсь, что никогда.

Comment: > Это как знаете заставить программиста писать string[] mas, вместо мне привычного string mas[].

Никаких проблем в этом нет. Разработчики пишут на разных языках, используя разные `coding convention`-ы в разных случаях. Для Java они свои, для Python - свои, для С++ - свои, для Delphi - свои. Кто не может - тех переучит `checkstyle`, автоматически откатывающий несоответвующие правилам оформления коммиты.

В Android вот так требуется именовать asset-ы. Просто примите это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IDEA не дает.

Не IDEA, а компилятор из Android SDK - это же написано в сообщении.

Вообще в Google работают далеко не глупые ребята, и если они поставили такое ограничение (`[a-z0-9_.]`) по сути на уровне контракта, значит на то были существенные причины.

Насколько я понимаю, сделано это для избежания проблем совместимости с файловыми системами, не чувствительными к регистру в именах файлов. Чтобы разработчик ненароком ногу себе не прострелил, создав пару файлов вида `myPicture.png` и `MyPicture.png`.

Comment: Жалко, конечно, что нельзя... Просто вряд ли бы программисты давали имена с большой буквы, в книгах везде пишут, что имена переменных нужно с маленьких букв писать... Какие-то странные стереотипы у Андроид разрабов... Немного даже обидно. ( Зря книги читал выходит.

Comment: > в книгах везде пишут что имена переменных нужно с маленьких букв писать

Это сильно зависит от конвенций принятых в конкретном языке и конкретной организации.

> Зря книги читал выходит.

Не думаю, что книги были посвящены исключительно регистру букв )

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не считал это проблемой, там сказано, что можно только буквы в маленьком регистре, цифры и _. В другом случае можно было бы их путать с методами класса или классами.

Comment: @Gorets, Максимум с чем их можно перепутать это с переменными. А как известно из книг по программированию. Все классы создаются с Большой буквы А переменные с маленькой. Так как же их перепутать то можно.


Но самое смешное в ваших словах это то чтобы найти класс с расширение PNG xDDD, напишите тоже.